# On what conditon the data gets loaded from DC

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

In my application data is getting loaded from DC based one a perticular condition, but we dont no how its getting loaded.
If i add one more condition, the data is loading but while submitt the mismatched condtion data is getting deleted from the db.
How to check where the data is coming from Dc to local DB in linq?. any flag we need to make true?

Comment: Code please. This can be anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a log property on the datacontext.  You can set a textwriter here so you can trace the generated queries.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.log.aspx

You could also do a sql trace to see what is going on.

Comment: Hi, i want to know how the fitlerting takes place,, because on one condition its filitering fine, if i add another my it will delete the one which does not meet  criteria in DB